# AWS elasticbeanstalk: httpd 2.4 uses 2.2 configuration with mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using elasticbeanstalk for my django application. But when I try to setup static / media files using:

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: static/
```

the wsgi.conf configuration generated for static files is:

```
  Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
  <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

However, this is not the configuration used with Apache 2.4.16. I believe it uses `Require all granted` instead of the above.

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. I'm very new to EBS.

Comment: If they have the appropriate compatibility module and directives set, the old way of doing things will still work in Apache 2.4.

Comment: Hi @GrahamDumpleton, it's difficult for me to believe that I got a reply from you. I've been following your blog for a while now, it's really informative.

Coming back to the issue, I think the instance is missing `mod_access_compat` module, which is causing this issue. I'll try adding it and see if everything works as expected. Thanks again! :)